# Regex para Cifras de site como CifraClub

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou precisando de uma Regex que funcione bem, e em JS, para pegar somente os acordes de uma cifra como esta: http://www.cifraclub.com.br/gui-rebustini/sou-um-altar/

O problema é que nunca mexi com Regex.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer capturar as cifras desse site com `Javascript` e `RegEx`? Edite sua pergunta para torná-la mais clara.

Comment: Eu tenho um projeto (livre) que faz isto. Acho que você gostará de ver a classe a seguir. Ela extrai título, artista, cifras etc.
https://github.com/colares/touke-flow/blob/master/Packages/Application/Apimenti.Translator/Classes/Apimenti/Translator/Service/SongParserService.php P.s.: o nome to projeto é ToUke: http://touke.dreamhosters.com
Código completo: https://github.com/colares/touke-flow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regex não é a ferramenta certa para esse problema. Inspecionando o código-fonte da página, vejo que as cifras estão cada uma em um elemento `b`, com a classe `_i0`, `_i1`, `_i2` e assim por diante (irrelevante nesse caso particular). O ideal então é pesquisar o DOM por esses elementos:

```javascript
var cifras = document.getElementById("ct_cifra")
                     .getElementsByTagName("b");
var texto = "";
for ( var i = 0 ; i < cifras.length ; i++ )
    texto += cifras[i].innerHTML + " ";
```

Se você quiser extrair essas cifras diretamente do site, pode usar um [bookmarklet](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) e exibir o texto resultante num `alert`, `console.log`, etc (algum lugar de onde você possa copiar e colar).

```
javascript:(function(){var cifras=document.getElementById("ct_cifra").getElementsByTagName("b");var texto='';for(var i=0;i<cifras.length;i++)texto+=cifras[i].innerHTML+' ';alert(texto);})();
```

<sub>**Nota:** código testado com sucesso no Firefox e Chrome, mas no Chrome não consegui selecionar o texto a partir do `alert` *dialog box* para copiar.</sub>

Comment: Entendi, só que o problema é o seguinte (Acho que não me expressei direito): Eu estou pegando o conteúdo da div que tem a cifra no CifraClub, e colocando no meu aplicativo, depois preciso conseguir separar da cifra o que é acorde e o que é letra da música, pra que depois consiga alterar o tom e etc...

Comment: @DouglasAraújo como você está pegando o conteúdo dessa div? Manualmente, programaticamente? O ideal seria aproveitar essa informação (markup) enquanto ela ainda existe; descartá-la (i.e. pegar só o texto) torna as coisas bem mais difíceis depois...

Comment: Sim, hoje (na aplicação antiga) pego com PHP e tiro as tags. Mas realmente, agora entendi seu ponto de vista. Seria melhor deixar, do que tirar e ter que olhar depois o que é acorde/letra. Mas a aplicação hoje funciona com PHP. Estava tentando fazer toda ela com JS. Mas pelo que falaram, vejo que não vai ser possível pegar a cifra do CifraClub com JS, certo?

Comment: @DouglasAraújo **no browser**, não, por razões de segurança. Mas como indicado por pagliuca, você pode fazer isso no lado servidor, usando V8 por exemplo (ou o node.js completo). Minha alternativa (bookmarklet) funciona, mas o usuário tem que navegar até a página e clicar no bookmarklet (você poderia a partir daí enviar o texto capturado pro servidor, em vez de exibir na tela). Além de trabalhoso, eu não recomendo, pois no geral bookmarklet é uma técnica bem pouco segura (o javascript roda no contexto da página, um código malicioso poderia fazer o que quisesse com ela).

Comment: Mas o objetivo de eu refazer a aplicação, era não usar nenhuma linguagem server-side... Node.js também depende de um servidor rodando, não?

Comment: @DouglasAraújo Sim, depende... Infelizmente isso que você quer não será possível, as questões de segurança têm prioridade no *browser*. Se um site pudesse ler conteúdos arbitrários de outros sites (sem a autorização dos mesmos - ver [CORS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) então nada importante/privado poderia ser feito num navegador.

Answer (score 2):

O seguinte código XPath retorna todas as cifras da página.

```
//pre[@id='ct_cifra']/b/text()
```

Basta adaptá-lo à linguagem que você está utilizando.

Para testá-lo, no Console JS do seu navegador, utilize a seguinte expressão:

```
$x("//pre[@id='ct_cifra']/b/text()")
```

Answer (score 1):

Estou assumindo que você se refere a Javascript no lado cliente (navegador), e não em uma aplicação servidor escrita em node.js, por exemplo.

O StackOverflow em inglês tem uma pergunta parecida:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597907/open-webpage-and-parse-it-using-javascript

A resposta mais votada indica que é impossível você fazer isso utilizando apenas Javascript, já que por questões de segurança, por ajax só é permitido carregar páginas do mesmo domínio que o seu.

Para carregar conteúdo de outro domínio, como é o seu caso, vai precisar de um script no lado servidor (em PHP, Python, Ruby, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/* A variável Cifra guarda a letra da música cifrada*/

$cifra = "E7     Amaj7
Antes de eu falar
             A9
Tu cantavas sobre mim
C#m               B4
    Tu tens sido tão
         A9
Tão bom     pra mim

C#m                   B4
    Antes de eu respirar
              A9
Sopraste Tua vida em mim
C#m               B4
    Tu tens sido tão
        A9
Tão bom    pra mim";

/* Esse é o padrão (regex) que utilizei para reconhecer todos os acordes da letra cifrada da variável acima */ 

$pattern = "/((?!(?<=[ÇçáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]))(((\b([A-G]{1,1}((?!([\scefghiklnopqrtuvxwyz]))((add|ADD)|#m|#|º|b)?([2-9]|m(\B|$)|maj|sus|dim|\(|º)?(\/[A-G][2-9](#|º)?(b{1,1})?)?(\+)?(\/([A-G]|[2-9]))?(º|#|b|\([2-9]\))?([2-9]|m)?(\+|(?<=[2-9])M)?(11|13)?(\/)?([A-G])?)([Eb|Bb])?(\([0-9]?[0-9]?(\/)?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?(\/1[1-9])?\b(\(((2|4|5|6|7|9|11|13)|[bB][2-9])\))?(-|\/[A-G])?(\/[2-9])?([2-9]|\)|\((b13|b11|b5)\)|\([2-9]\)|-|\/)?(\+)?)(m|b|º|#|13|add[2-9]\))?)|\b(?(?<=(?<=\s)[A-G](?=\s)))[A-G](?!(\s)?[a-zH-Z])\b)(º)?)((\(([0-9]{1,2})?(\-)?(\+)?\))|(?!((?:[çáéíóúÇÁÉÍÓÚ])|((\t|\s)[a-zA-Z][A-Z]|\s[A-G][a-z]\w|\s[A-G]\s\w[H-Z])\w?)))|(?(?<=(?<=\s)[A-G]M|[A-G]m|[A-G]m(?=\s)))([A-G]m|[A-G]M(?!\s))(#|b)?([2-9]|maj|sus|dim|º|º)?(\/[A-G][2-9](#)?(b{1,1})?)?(\+)?(\/([A-G]|[2-9]))?(#|b|\([2-9]\))?([2-9])?(\+)?(\([A-G][2-9]\))?(\([1-9][1-9]?\))?(11|13)?(-|\/[A-G])?(\/[2-9])?([2-9]|-|\/)?(\+)?(b|#|13)?(?!(\s)?[a-zH-Z])(?!(?:[,çáéíóúÇÁÉÍÓÚ]))\W)/";

/* Apliquei abaixo o comando preg_replace que coloca todas ocorrências (acordes) encontradas entre as tags </b>*/    

$cifra = preg_replace($pattern, "<b>$1</b>", $cifra);

echo "<pre>". $cifra ."</pre>";
```

Comment: Coloque uma explicação de como esse código funciona.